# can laravel eloquent models do aritmitic on select statments?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to do selection from the database similar to this sql statment with laravel? Or will I have to add a win_percent column and do the calculation manually when adding new entries to the database?

> select *, wins / (wins + losses) AS win_percent

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: You can do any SQL query with Laravel...